Does anyone know PHP code to correct the conflictive time change in a country?
For example, when a country changes time, there are 2 possibilities:
1.- If it changes to an earlier time, for example, at 3 Am in Central Europe, the last Sunday in October at 3 Am becomes 2 Am, therefore, if there is a date that is 02:30 am, 2 Dates and Hours are possible, one before the Change, and one after the Change.
2.- In Central Europe the Last Sunday of March at 2 Am becomes 3 Am, therefore if someone puts a date/time like this: 03-31-2024 at 02:30 Am, that LOCAL time It is theoretically impossible, since between 2 and 3 there is no possibility of Local Time.
Is there any code that warns about this?
For example, I have this code in PHP, I pass it a time zone, and it does not warn me that this time, 02:30:00Am, is not officially possible, and I would like it to warn me about these conflicting hours:
(The code has an error in JulianDay, below I make a comment with the correction, it is a small error, the link is already corrected)
https://timezonespro.com/php/test4.php?tzname=Europe/Madrid
<?php
$timezoneStr = $_GET["tzname"];
echo "TimeZone = " . $timezoneStr;


$datetime = "2024-03-31 02:30:00";
print '<br>';
echo "Local = " . $datetime;
$given = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone($timezoneStr));
$given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$output = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
print '<br>';
echo "UTC = " . $output;

$ano = substr($output, 0, 4);
$mes = substr($output, 5, 2);
$dia = substr($output, 8, 2);
$hor = substr($output, 11, 2);
$min = substr($output, 14, 2);
$sec = substr($output, 17, 2);
print '<br>';
echo "Year = " . $ano;
print '<br>';
echo "Month = " . $mes;
print '<br>';
echo "Day = " . $dia;
print '<br>';
echo "Hours = " . $hor;
print '<br>';
echo "Minutes = " . $min;
print '<br>';
echo "Seconds = " . $sec;

$meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
$mesStr = $meses[intval($mes) - 1];

print '<br>';
echo $dia . "-" . $mesStr . "-" . $ano . " a las " . $hor . ":" . $min . ":" . $sec;

$secondsInTime = intval($hor * 3600) + intval($min * 60) + intval($sec);
$secondsInTimeDec = $secondsInTime / 86400;

$jd = GregorianToJD($mes, $dia, $ano);
$jdDec = intval($jd) + $secondsInTimeDec;
print '<br>';
echo "JulianDay = " . $jdDec;
?>

A code that warns of conflicting times in time changes in a country.

DateTime already handles such cases:
$dt = new DateTime('2024-03-31 02:30:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // prints: 2024-03-31 03:30:00

Notice how the "impossible" 02:30 became 03:30 automatically.
There is no warning, but you can always compare the formatted Y-m-d H:i:s strings of the date with and without timezone info, if you need to check if that happened.

As lafor noted, PHPs DateTime handles this for you.
Add these lines after you create $given DateTime object:
if ($given->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') != $datetime) {
    echo "WARNING: $datetime is impossible in $timezoneStr. Automatically adjusted to account for daylight savings time.";
}

<?php
$timezoneStr = $_GET["tzname"];
echo "TimeZone = " . $timezoneStr;


$datetime = "2024-03-31 02:30:00";
print '<br>';
echo "Local = " . $datetime;
$given = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone($timezoneStr));

// check if $given was adjusted for daylight savings in locale
if ($given->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') != $datetime) {
    echo "WARNING: $datetime is impossible in $timezoneStr. Automatically adjusted to account for daylight savings time.";
}


$given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$output = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
print '<br>';
echo "UTC = " . $output;

$ano = substr($output, 0, 4);
$mes = substr($output, 5, 2);
$dia = substr($output, 8, 2);
$hor = substr($output, 11, 2);
$min = substr($output, 14, 2);
$sec = substr($output, 17, 2);
print '<br>';
echo "Year = " . $ano;
print '<br>';
echo "Month = " . $mes;
print '<br>';
echo "Day = " . $dia;
print '<br>';
echo "Hours = " . $hor;
print '<br>';
echo "Minutes = " . $min;
print '<br>';
echo "Seconds = " . $sec;

$meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
$mesStr = $meses[intval($mes) - 1];

print '<br>';
echo $dia . "-" . $mesStr . "-" . $ano . " a las " . $hor . ":" . $min . ":" . $sec;

$secondsInTime = intval($hor * 3600) + intval($min * 60) + intval($sec);
$secondsInTimeDec = $secondsInTime / 86400;

$jd = GregorianToJD($mes, $dia, $ano);
$jdDec = intval($jd) + $secondsInTimeDec;
print '<br>';
echo "JulianDay = " . $jdDec;
?>


BTW - you may want to check out Carbon. I have nothing to do with it's development, but I've used it whenever possible since I discovered a few years ago. It has saved me countless headaches.

Many thanks, good code, I test!!! Thanks rileys...

Thank you very much Rileys!!! One question, if you can, and in the other change? Is there a PHP little code - how you write, a simple and little usseful code - that warns that there are 2 possible hours? For example, on October 27, 2024, the time will change in Central Europe, at 03:00:00 Am it will become 02:00:00 Am, and there will be 2 possible hours between 02:00:00 and 02:59:59... For example, at 02:30:00, there will be 02:30:00 am before the Change, and 02:30:00 after the Change. Is there something in PHP that warns that there will be 2 possible hours? Thanks in advance.

Glad it worked. Don't forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted. Madrid loses an hour on 2024-10-27 in which case there will be 02:30 before the change, then after 02:59 the clocks will reset back to 02:00 and you will see 02:30 again. However, PHP does not have any way of knowing which 02:30 you are talking about when you construct a DateTime with "2024-10-27 02:30:00". However, if you use Carbon with string "2024-10-27 01:30:00" and add two hours, it will correctly say the time is still 02:30. Carbon::parse("2024-10-27 01:30:00", "Europe/Madrid")->addHours(2)

My problem is to waste time knowing how Carbon works, and I think it can be done with the PHP functions, I did something, and it works well, but not perfect, I have to look at how to handle when the changes are delaying the time, with getTransitions(); It should be possible to do it, I'm checking... But very grateful for your time Rileys...

A little error in my code in the JulianDay, correction:
    <?php
$timezoneStr = $_GET["tzname"];
echo "TimeZone = " . $timezoneStr;


$datetime = "2024-03-31 02:30:00";
print '<br>';
echo "Local = " . $datetime;
//$given = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
$given = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone($timezoneStr));
$given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$output = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
print '<br>';
echo "UTC = " . $output;

$ano = substr($output, 0, 4);
$mes = substr($output, 5, 2);
$dia = substr($output, 8, 2);
$hor = substr($output, 11, 2);
$min = substr($output, 14, 2);
$sec = substr($output, 17, 2);
print '<br>';
echo "Year = " . $ano;
print '<br>';
echo "Month = " . $mes;
print '<br>';
echo "Day = " . $dia;
print '<br>';
echo "Hours = " . $hor;
print '<br>';
echo "Minutes = " . $min;
print '<br>';
echo "Seconds = " . $sec;

$meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
$mesStr = $meses[intval($mes) - 1];

print '<br>';
echo $dia . "-" . $mesStr . "-" . $ano . " a las " . $hor . ":" . $min . ":" . $sec;

$secondsInTime = intval($hor * 3600) - intval(12 * 3600) + intval($min * 60) + intval($sec);
$secondsInTimeDec = $secondsInTime / 86400;

$jd = GregorianToJD($mes, $dia, $ano);
$jdDec = intval($jd) + $secondsInTimeDec;
print '<br>';
echo "JulianDay = " . $jdDec;
?>

The correction is this part:
$secondsInTime = intval($hor * 3600) - intval(12 * 3600) + intval($min * 60) + intval($sec);

Because the JulianDay init at 12 Noon, for this, is needed add "- intval(12 * 3600)"
And well, it is possible to list all the time changes, and search for the dates that have these problems, but I was looking to see if there was someone who had already done it.
For example, with this code you can list all changes in the "Europe/Madrid" TimeZone, And then check if the date-time is part of the problems with time changes:
https://timezonespro.com/php/get_from_tz_allchanges_b.php?tzname=Europe/Madrid
Code:
<?php
$timezoneStr = $_GET["tzname"];
print_r('timezone = ' . $timezoneStr . '@');
print '<br>';
$timezone_identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
for ($i=0; $i < 1005; $i++)
    {
    if ($timezone_identifiers[$i] == "")
        break;
    else if ($timezone_identifiers[$i] == $timezoneStr)
        {
        $timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone_identifiers[$i]);
        $transitions = $timezone->getTransitions();
        for ($k=0; $k<500; $k++)
            {
            if ($transitions[$k] == "")
                break;
            $UnixTimeStamp = $transitions[$k][ts];
            $julianDay = ($UnixTimeStamp / 86400) + 2440587.5;
            print_r('UnixTimeStamp = ' . $UnixTimeStamp . ' | ');
            print_r('JulianDay = ' . $julianDay . ' | ');
            print_r('DateTime (Time) = ' . $transitions[$k][time] . ' | ');
            print_r('Seconds Difference to GMT (Offset) = ' . $transitions[$k][offset] . ' | ');
            print_r('Is Dst (IsDst) = ' . $transitions[$k][isdst] . ' | ');
            print_r('TimeZone Abreviation (Abbr) = ' . $transitions[$k][abbr] . '@');
            Print '<br>';
            }
        return;
        }
    }
return;

?>
I'm looking to see if there was already someone who had done it. Well, it should be something that has been done for a long time, these types of problems with time changes are always there.
And I think that php should already have it corrected, and when there are officially impossible hours, notify, and when there are possible double hours, also notify.
It must be taken into account that when a Country changes and delays the time, there will always be and have been 2 possible hours, the example I gave, October 27, 2024 in Central Europe at 03:00:00 Am, becomes 02:00:00 Am, therefore there are 2 Possible Hours:
For example:
October 27, 2024 at 02:30:00
It can be 02:30:00 am before the change is made, or 02:30:00 am after the change is made, and I have seen that in many sites they do not correct it - php does not give a warning either -, and therefore, for example, for JulianDay data used in Astronomy, it is a problem, since there are 2 possible Juliandays, and that changes a lot at the Astronomical level.
And the same when the change is the other way around, if 2 am becomes 3 am, as official hours, because officially there are no intermediate hours between 02:00:00 and 02:59:59. And for questions of perfection, and especially in Astronomy, it is important to keep this in mind.

THIS CODE WORK!!!
It needs to be polished a little for each person's needs, but it works well - I think, although I still have to check with other time zones, but I think it works well -.
But it ALREADY NOTIFIES if the date/time for a Time Zone is Impossible - in case a Place changes the Official Time by Adding, that is, that, for example, at 02:00:00 Am it becomes 03:00:00 Am and set a Date Time like 02:30:00 Am, a Time that is Officially Not Possible -.
And it ALREADY NOTIFIES if the date/Time for a Time Zone has 2 Possible Hours, one before the Change and another after the Change - in case a Place changes the Official Time Subtracting, that is, for example, at 03:00:00 Am becomes 02:00:00 Am and the hour is set as 02:30:00 Am, a time that may be before the change or after the change.
https://timezonespro.com/php/test8b.php?tzname=Europe/Madrid
Code here:
https://timezonespro.com/php/test8b.txt
The correction of JulianDay that I commented in a message below is already put in the code and everything has been checked.
Greetings... Thanks rileys!!!
